# How to read the content of JSON file in a Code Repository

Tags: palantir-foundry

**Problem context:**

I would like to apply a transform to all the datasets in a folder. I am using the [Compass Files Lister Logic Flow](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/building-pipelines/create-a-connected-flow/) which generates a list of resource IDs stored in a JSON file which is added to a code repository of your choice.

**Question:**

How do I read the JSON file in my code repository?

**Failed solutions:**

The JSON file is not a dataset stored outside the code repository so I can't use a transform to read it, which as far as I know is the only way you can read files from a code repository.

I tried adding a `with open()`: to the transform generator function in my code repository but Python was unable to read the file.

```
with open('./rids.json', 'r') as fileme:
    data = json.load(fileme)

data = data['childrenRids']
```

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Does https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/read-files-repository/ help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read any file present in a repository into transform context you need to add it to `package_data` in the `setup.py` file.

Here's the documentation explaining how to do it: https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/read-files-repository/