# Palantir Foundry Compass File Lister - How to use generated json file as transform inputs?

Tags: palantir-foundry

My question is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76540394/how-to-read-the-content-of-json-file-in-a-code-repository), but the answer hasn't gotten me to 100%. I am trying to use the output of the Compass Files Lister logic flow as a transform input. Here is what I have so far, but I'm missing something to make this work. I followed the steps in [this documentation](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/read-files-repository/) to load json files.

The code below runs great in Preview and gives the expected output dataframe, but on building, the checks fail with "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'". It doesn't seem to be able to run the code  that loads the json file outside of the compute function.

Also Palantir friends, if I could suggest - it would be very helpful if the compass file lister documentation could be updated with a sample of how to do this! It seems like this tool was built specifically for this purpose, but nowhere in the docs does it cover how to actually use the json file in a transform.

How do I load the json file RIDs and use them as inputs to the transform?

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from transforms.api import transform, Input, Output
from pkg_resources import resource_stream
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
import yaml

# rids.json is created by Compass Files Lister logic flow
stream = resource_stream(__name__, "rids.json")
docs = yaml.safe_load(stream)
raw_datasets = docs["childrenRids"]


@transform(
    output=Output("output name"),
    **{
        raw_dataset: Input(raw_dataset)
        for raw_dataset in raw_datasets
    }
)
def compute(output, **transform_inputs):
    processed_dataframes = []
    for input_name, transform_input in transform_inputs.items():  # noqa
        input_dataframe = transform_input.dataframe()
        processed_dataframes.append(input_dataframe.withColumn(
            "data_source",
            F.lit(input_name)
        ))

    df = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, processed_dataframes)
    output.write_dataframe(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, thanks friends for going on this adventure with me. This was user error - I installed the pyyaml package instead of yaml and it works now. It's still 'import yaml' either way. Hopefully this full code sample can help someone else!